# TypeScript confusing errors 'Object is possibly 'undefined' & 'Property 'length' does not exist on type'

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, undefined

I'm a bit new to TypeScript, just adding its functionality to my React app. So I encountered two confusing errors:

1. "Object is possibly 'undefined'" on the last "data[card.key]"
2. "Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | any[] | IPerson'"

I have the following code:

```
const filteredCards = cards.filter(card => (card.allData || (data[card.key] && data[card.key].length)))
```

First error is strange, because I use previous check to sort this out (if it is 'undefined' that is what the filter method is for, to filter out this card).

As for the second error, this is to check that this card is an Array and it is not empty.
In the interface of "data" I have stated:

```
[key: string]: string | IPerson | Array<any> | undefined
```

So the compiler tells me that "data[card.key]" could be not an array or a string and thus will have no length. But that is ok, it will just return "undefined" and this card will also be filtered out.

Anyway, if I change this code to something more obvious, it works fine with no typescript errors.

```
const filteredCards = cards.filter(card => {
    if (card.allData) return true
    const subData = data[card.key]
    if (subData && Array.isArray(subData)) if (subData.length) return true
    return false
})
```

Can someone explain to me, what is the problem so I could avoid this in the future?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> First error is strange, because I use previous check to sort this out...

I suspect the issue is with `data`, not `data[card.key]`. So you'd need `data && data[card.key] &&`

> So the compiler tells me that "data[card.key]" could be not an array or a string and thus will have no length. But that is ok, it will just return "undefined" and this card will also be filtered out.

That's not how a static type system works. It's how *JavaScript* works, yes, but the whole point of TypeScript is to catch type-related errors early. Since `string` and (I'm guessing) `IPerson` don't have a `length` property, you can't use `length` unless you narrow the type to weed out `string` and `IPerson`. For instance: `&& "length" in data[card.key] && data[card.key].length`.

So combining those two things you'd have:

```typescript
const filteredCards = cards.filter(
    card => card.allData || (data && data[card.key] && "length" in data[card.key] && data[card.key].length)
);
```

With all the repetition there, I'd probably cache `data[card.key]` to a variable:

```typescript
const filteredCards = cards.filter(card => {
    if (card.allData) {
        return true;
    }
    const entry = data && data[card.key];
    return entry && "length" in entry && entry.length;
});
```

Comment: No, the first fix doesn't work. "data" comes from props and is typed as necessary. And this "[key: string]: string | IPerson | Array<any> | undefined" tells typescript that data[card.key] can possibly be 'undefined'. But I don't see why it is a problem. 
The second fix unfortunately also doesn't work. Still get the same error.
Thanks anyway

Comment: @keXXpert - We can't help you more than with general advice like the above without more information to work with, such as a [mre].